# How to wrap text in React Native's Picker?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a really narrow picker due to the lengthy selectedValue.
How do i wrap the selectedValue so it will show the full value without using the double dots (..) at the end of the value?

[image]

And also, is there any way to resize the font? I found out you can use itemStyles props, but that's only for iOS.